# GMOCK Clang pesky error "/usr/include/limits.h:123:16: fatal error: 'limits.h' file not found"

Tags: c++, clang++, googlemock

Using Linux OS for C++ development with GMOCK framework.  I have the following code.

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "dispat_tasks.hh"

namespace testing {

namespace internal {
    GTEST_API_ string JoinAsTuple(const Strings& fields);
}

namespace DispatTasksTestNS {
using ::testing::Invoke;

// Fixture
class DispatTasksTest : public ::testing::Test {
 public:
    DispatTasksTest() {}
    ~DispatTasksTest() {}
    dispat_tasks SMD;
};
}  // testing NS
}
```

When I execute the clang syntax checking, I get the flowing error.

```
/usr/include/limits.h:123:16: fatal error: 'limits.h' file not found
```

The content of the line 123 is:

```
# include_next <limits.h>
```

Any way to resolve the error above?

Comment: Is there another `limits.h` on the search path that exists after the directory this `limits.h` is in?

Comment: I am seeing with with `clang` on `TravisCI`.

Comment: I was seeing that error for a while. After trying many things, I think the one that fixed it was compiling Google Test with a specific standard flag:
`cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++14" /usr/src/gtest/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libc++1
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libc++-dev
```

fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

when used clang

I try `-I/usr/lib64/clang/9.0.1/include/` solved my problem.
The `/usr/include/limits.h` will start to find an alternated `limits.h`, which should fit the compiler's environment.

Try to find out some folder like `/xxx/xxx/compiler_you_used/xxx/include`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did, in Ubuntu Linux.

In terminal:

```
sudo find -name "limits.h"
```

From the list I chose the `usr/include` folder and added the following compiler option:

`isystem /usr/include`

this solved my problem.